# How can I use custom padding in Node js encryption and decryption?

Tags: java, node.js, encryption, node-crypto

While I was going through a piece of code in JAVA for encryption there is padding mechanism we can provide while creating cipher instance.

> ```
>         final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/ISO10126Padding");
> ```

Here we can specify the padding to be used.

How can i achieve the same in Node.js?

Use Case: I am decrypting the data which i have encrypted via JAVA using this method.

Note: In Java i can encrypt & decrypt by creating the cipher instance the above provided way and getting success response.
Let me know if any other info required.

Comment: The *crypto* module of NodeJS uses PKCS#7 padding by default. If a different padding should be applied, the padding can be disabled with [`setAutoPadding(false)`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#ciphersetautopaddingautopadding) and a custom padding/unpadding can be implemented (which is not very elaborate). ISO 10126 is described e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#ISO_10126). Alternatively, another NodeJS library can be used, e.g. [*CryptoJS*](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#block-modes-and-padding).